# Fastest way to iterate 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, pointers

I have a class that wraps 2d float[][] array into 1d float[] array:

```
class Wrapper
{
   int CountX;
   int CountY;
   float[] Values;
}
```

for example something like this

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{5, 6, 7, 8}
```

would be wrapped into

```
var wr = new Wrapper
{
  Values = new float[8]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
  CountX = 4,
  CountY = 2
};
```

And I want to find the fastest way to get its row or column.
Currently I'm using these methods

```
class Wrapper
{
   int CountX;
   int CountY;
   float[] Values;

   public float[] GetRow(int row)
   {
       var res = new float[CountX];
       for(int i = 0; i < CountX; i++)
       {
           res[i] = Values[CountX*row + i];
       }
       return res;
   }

   public float[] GetColumn(int column)
   {
       var res = new float[CountY];
       for (int i = 0; i < CountY; i++)
       {
           res[i] = Values[column + CountX*i];
       }
       return res;
   }
}
```

With this usage:

```
var wr = new Wrapper
{
  Values = new float[8]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
  CountX = 4,
  CountY = 2
};

//{1, 2, 3, 4}
//{5, 6, 7, 8}

wr.GetRow(1) // 5 6 7 8
wr.GetColumn(3) // 4 8
```

And what I am trying to accomplish is increasing performance. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it faster using unsafe code, but I don't really know how to use pointers in C#

Comment: "increasing performance" Why do you care? Do you have a **specific** issue? Did you measure of this code causes problems in your actual workflow? This cries for premature micro-optimizations.

Comment: If you are going to use pointers for this due to performance reasons, then you probably chose the wrong development environment to begin with.... Why this need for speed? Is this a benchmarked and identified bottleneck in your code? Or is this a solid case of premature optimization?

Comment: What is increasing performance? Is it faster access? Faster creation? Memory fingerprint? GC pressure? Performance questions should be backed up up by specific performance issues carefully measured and identified with real case data. For example, if these type of array wrappers are created seldomly but accesed repeatedly, maybe precomputing rows and columns is actually the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to do this would usually be to *not* allocate or copy anything. Switching to `unsafe` is not going to help much with the real cost here, which is the allocation and copy; at best you can avoid some bounds checks.

Assuming you keep a 1D backing array, on the minor axis (by which I mean: contiguous data), it should be trivially possible to get a `Span<float>` of the relevant chunk of data: nothing more than that i.e. `new ReadOnlySpan<float>(Values, CountX*row, CountX)`; on the major axis, maybe return something that is simply a flyweight `readonly struct` with an indexer into the data?

However, honestly I wonder if you should just use a `float[,]` and use regular x/y indexing.

---

Example; note that choosing which dimension to use as the inner one is important, as the direct `Span<T>` access will be faster than the indirect `Row<T>` access:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

var obj = new ArrayWrapper<float>(2, 3);
obj[1, 2] = 4;
Write(obj);
var row = obj.GetColumn(1);
for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
    row[i] = i;
Write(obj);
var col = obj.GetRow(1);
for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
    col[i] = i + 10;
Write(obj);
col = obj.GetRow(2);
for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
    col[i] = i + 20;
Write(obj);
static void Write(ArrayWrapper<float> arr)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < arr.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Width; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[x, y]);
            Console.Write('\t');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

readonly struct ArrayWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] _array;
    public int Width => _array.GetLength(0);
    public int Height => _array.GetLength(1);
    public ArrayWrapper(int width, int height) => _array = new T[width, height];
    public ref T this[int x, int y] => ref _array[x, y];
    public readonly Span<T> GetColumn(int x)
        => MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref _array[x, 0], Height);
    public readonly Row<T> GetRow(int y) => new(_array, y);
}
readonly struct Row<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] _array;
    private readonly int _y;

    public Row(T[,] array, int y)
    {
        _array = array;
        _y = y;
    }
    public bool IsEmpty => Length == 0;
    public int Length => _array.GetLength(0); // Width
    public ref T this[int x] => ref _array[x, _y];
}
```

Comment: thanks ReadonlySpan worked fine. Maybe you also have any idea about GetColumn()?

Comment: @VitaliDzikavitski see edit; I have columns as direct and rows as indirect; you can reverse that if needed, by switching the array axes

Comment: @MarcGravell I would be a bit careful with using 2D arrays, at least for representing things like images. It tend to make interoperability more difficult, notably because the images will be column-major (if using [x,y]), instead of row major that is much more common.

Comment: @JonasH that's fair; converting the above to use a 1D array would be pretty minimal, and I already called out that picking the major vs minor axes is important; the main change would be the need to store at least one axis length

Answer (score 1):

For rows you should return a `ReadonlySpan<T>` since that would be a zero-copy operation. This is assuming your storage is row-major.

For columns you will need to copy elements. It can be useful to take the destination as a parameter. That way it might be possible to avoid repeated allocations. You can also update the index directly in the loop, I would expect that to help a little bit, but I have not done any profiling.

```
public void CopyColumn(int column, Span<float> res)
{
       for (int i = column; i < Values.Length; i += CountX)
       {
           res[i] = Values[i];
       }
}
```

If you want an array as a result you can add a helper method:

```
public float[] GetColumn(int column){
    var res = new float[CountY];
    CopyColumn(column, res);
    return res;
}
```